# Set ulimit to defaults

Tags: ulimit

I set ulimits to fullfill memory demands of Git. Do we have anyway to reset ulimits to defaults, I mean what they were before I set them.
Please keep in mind I am doing it from Python script

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1689505/python-ulimit-and-nice-for-subprocess-call-subprocess-popen?

Answer (score 5):

`ulimit` only sets properties for the current shell. Once you leave the shell everything is back to normal:

```
michas@lenny:~$ ulimit 
unlimited
michas@lenny:~$ (ulimit 4; ulimit)
4
michas@lenny:~$ ulimit
unlimited
michas@lenny:~$
```

Comment: I am doing from Python script.

Comment: how are you "doing it from a Python script"? *current shell* in this answer really should read *current process (and child-processes)*

Comment: What do you mean?.Please elaborate.I want to set and unset ulimits from Python script